# Torch animation js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to create animation on my web page.
Something like this, but without using canvas [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ARTsinn/AwgQ6/).

```js
// Div's for logging
var logDiv = document.getElementById("log");
var logDetailsDiv = document.getElementById("logDetails");

// Div containing our image
var divPloatje = document.getElementById('ploatje');

// Initial Mouse coords
var mouse = {
    x: -100,
    y: -100
};

// Fire of the Mask function so the mask is automagically following whatever is in the mouse var.
fixMask();


if ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement) {
    // Touch events available, wire to touchStart and touchMove
    divPloatje.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove, false);
    divPloatje.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, false);
    divPloatje.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd, false);
} else {
    // Touch events not available, wire to touchMove only
    divPloatje.addEventListener('mousemove', touchMove, false);
}


function touchStart(e) {
    console.debug("Touch Start! " + e.type + " event=" + inspect(e));
    //logDetails( inspect( e.touches.item(0) ) );  
    e.preventDefault(); // PreventDefault prevents native scrolling on device
    return false;
}

function touchMove(e) {

    if (e.touches == null) {
        // No touch available fallback to mouse
        mouse = getMouse(e, divPloatje);
        console.debug("Mouse Move");
    } else {
        //Touch available
        var targetEvent = e.touches.item(0);
        //log("[x,y] from target=" + targetEvent.clientX + "," + targetEvent.clientY );  
        // Assign clientX and ClientY values to mouse.x,y 
        mouse.x = targetEvent.clientX;
        mouse.y = targetEvent.clientY;
        // console.debug("Touch Move");  
    }

    //log("[x,y] in mouse=" + mouse.x + "," + mouse.y );  

    //logDetails( inspect( e ) );  
    e.preventDefault(); // Kill native scroll again, might be double measure, not shure... ;-)
    return false;
}

function touchEnd(e) {
    console.debug("touchEnd (!)");
    //  var strImage = '-webkit-radial-gradient('+ mouse.x+'px '+mouse.y+'px,10px 10px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 30%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%)';
    //divPloatje.style.WebkitMaskImage = strImage;
}


// This function is scheduled by using RequestAnimationFrame
// Should provide smoother animation but I'm on the fence here.
// My S3 is loving it, my Tegra tablet seems slower...


function fixMask() {
    webkitRequestAnimationFrame(fixMask);
    // Create string for -webkit-mask-image CSS attribute
    var strImage = '-webkit-radial-gradient(' + mouse.x + 'px ' + mouse.y + 'px,100px 100px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 80%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 100%)';
    divPloatje.style.WebkitMaskImage = strImage;


    //log("WebKitMaskImage:" + strImage);
}

// Util Functions


function getMouse(e, canvas) {
    var element = canvas,
        offsetX = 0,
        offsetY = 0,
        mx, my;

    // Compute the total offset. It's possible to cache this if you want
    if (element.offsetParent !== undefined) {
        do {
            offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
            offsetY += element.offsetTop;
        } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
    }

    mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
    my = e.pageY - offsetY;

    // We return a simple javascript object with x and y defined
    return {
        x: mx,
        y: my
    };
}

function log(text) {
    logDiv.innerHTML = text;
}

function inspect(obj) {
    if (typeof obj === "undefined") {
        return "undefined";
    }
    var _props = [];

    for (var i in obj) {
        _props.push(i + " : " + obj[i]);
    }
    return " {" + _props.join(",<br>") + "} ";
}
```

```css
body{
  background: #000000;
}

.ploatjeClass{
  position:absolute;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 683px;
  background: url(http://gp1.pinkbike.org/p5pb8847293/p5pb8847293.jpg);
  
}

#log{
  color:#ffffff;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;  
}

#logDetails{
  color:#ffffff;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="ploatje" class="ploatjeClass"></div>
<div id="log"></div>  
<div id="logDetails"></div>
```

but now i am confusing cause I 
have no idea how to do it. Is it really possible if yes, how?
I also have background image and overlay with some color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with css clipping masks, try it:

https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/